# A non-tedious way to prove what is an intuitively obvious subset sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If you have nonnegative integers $a,b,c$ such that $a+2b+5c=32$, what's the easiest way to prove that there exist some nonnegative integers $a'\leq a,b'\leq b,c'\leq c$ such that $a'+2b'+5c'=20$?

The only thing I can think to do is to do tedious casewise work, but there has to be an easier way. Is there some more general result in number theory or something that handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt at non-tedious case work.

- If $a\ge 12$, then set $(a',b',c') = (a-12,b,c)$.
- If $b\ge 6$, then set $(a',b',c') = (a,b-6,c)$.
- If $c\ge 2$, then set $(a',b',c') = (a-2,b,c-2)$ or $(a',b',c') = (a,b-1,c-2)$.

All that remains to be proved is that one of the three cases always occurs (easy proof by contradiction) and that one of the options in the last case is possible (look modulo $5$).

Comment: +1 As a variant of "one of the options in the last case is possible", we can first show that there are solutions to $a'' + 2b'' + 5c'' = 30$ and then solutions to $a' + 2b' + 5c' = 20$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $a' = a, a > 0$.

We have

$$a + 2b + 5c = 32$$
$$a + 2b' + 5c' = 20$$

Subtracting,

$2(b - b') + 5(c - c') = 12$

Since $GCD(2, 5) = 1$, this equation has infinitely many solutions in $Z$ that can be determined using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

We can observe that $c - c' = 2, b - b' = 1$ where $c,c',b,b' \in Z$ is a solution. Therefore, we can choose $c,c',b,b' \in Z_{+}$

Hence the proof.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases (for example, $a=32$).